# Multiple Infinite Threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hey :) it is not really a practical example. It's just to test some things.

The threads are supposed to represent independent input objects which randomly create data and send this data to another receiver object.

My problem is that i want them to create data for an infinite time. But as i start the first thread it gets stuck cause of the while loop.

How is it possible to start multiple infinite threads?

## class A:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class A
{

public:

    A()        : m_ID(-1)  {}
    A(int _ID) : m_ID(_ID) {}
    ~A()                   {}

public:

    void DoWork()
    {
        std::thread T(&A::Work, this);

        T.join();
    }

private:

    void Work()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // do stuff
            std::cout << m_ID << "\n";
        }
    }

private:

    int m_ID;

};
```

## main.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"

static const unsigned int s_NumberOfObjects = 5;

void main()
{
    A As[s_NumberOfObjects];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s_NumberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        As[i] = A(i);
    }


    for (size_t i = 0; i < s_NumberOfObjects; i++)
    {
        As[i].DoWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the line `T.join();` from `A::DoWork()`

Comment: then i get the error: R6010 - abort() has been called

Comment: Put a `T.detach()` instead.

Comment: nice :) thanks alot

Comment: Warning: Downside to `detatch` is now the program can exit before the thread completes. Bad thing to do in a non-trivial program.

Answer (score 1):

make the thread a member variable, and move the `join` function to `A` destructor

```
class A{
  /* ... */

public:
   ~A() {  m_Worker.join(); }

/*...*/
 void DoWork()
{
    m_Worker = std::thread(&A::Work, this);
}

private:
   int m_ID;
   std::thread m_Worker;

};
```

using `detach` is highly discouraged as you loose all track for the thread and you have no way to tell it to shut down cleanly when the application terminates.

Comment: does not work for me. VisualStudio tells me that the function operator= for std::thread is a deleted function

Comment: Visual Studio Professional 2013

Comment: switch to VS 2015. VS2013 is full of bugs.